# What is the real number of results in Google Images Search

Tags: google-image-search

[Google Image Search](http://www.google.com.vn/search?um=1&hl=vi&safe=off&biw=1599&bih=809&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=google&oq=google&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=65164l65411l0l2l2l0l0l0l0l197l197l0.1l1)

Anyone know why when I search images in Google Image Search, in this example, the input is "Google", it says there are about 872.000.000 results. Then some images are thumbnails display together with a "Show More Results" button. But even when I click on that button, the results turn out only a thousand images only.

Any way for me to get the full results?