# Google reverse image search in a specific country

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

I want to use Google to search for a specific image inside a specific **country (IP)!**

Using http://images.google.com/ gives me results for all sites, but I can't sort results by country. It would also be useful to limit by country domain ".si" or ".co.uk".

Adding "site:.co.uk" after my image upload doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- in regular image search, this **is possible**:

  > **`tennis ball site:*.co.uk`**
  >
  > [image: 1]
- in reverse image search this **does not work**:

  > **`tennis ball site:*.co.uk`**
  >
  > [image: 2]
- **but** there is an option to use browser search invoked by **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>F</kbd>** on top of the reverse search:

  > [image: 3]

Comment: Thank you Mark for you answer but it does not work for me. I'm showing you my technique: I upload logo to Image reverse search, it displays 25.000.000.000 matches and has results below. As you can see (attachment) I am interested in results from a specific country (let say UK), but there are some DE, COM, UK results. I would like to filter for only UK results. Matches are OK, but I can't go through all results.. I need somethig to filter by country/IP/domain.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bqbldIC

Comment: @Andrej click on "All sizes"

Comment: @Andrej https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123992/186471

Comment: Thank you I see what you did. It still does not show all results. I7M interested in the end of the attachment where it says: "Pages that include matching images". There are my true results, just need to filter them somehow by country/ip/doman.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a solution for you. If you can find the image on site in your country, copy the URL of the picture instead. Use google for reverse image search and insert the URL instead of the image...results are much better.