# Google gives incomplete results on self search

Tags: google-search

I recently did a search on my own name, and three email addresses I've used over the last 30 years.  I have done this before, and I typically get something like 100,000 hits, with a lot of them dating back to the days of usenet.

Recently when I ran this search, The initial screen said 14,000 hits, then on clicking page 2, I ended up with 97

The distribution of hits is odd too:  I have a few from various Stack Exchange posts, but I've written hundreds.  I have a few from Medium.com, Quora, and a single one from Slashdot from decades ago.  All of these are sites where I have written a lot.  But I am also indexed on sites where I may have made a single response to a blog.

- Why are my search results so incomplete?
- How can I get a complete list of every post I've written anywhere on the internet?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123992/186471

Comment: In terms of depth of search, try running it in Private/Incognito, etc. to compare the numbers.  I don't have any direct evidence for it, but it seems that when you run it with your current store of cookies, logins, etc., Gmail tends to ignore some of the results that may be "old" to you.  The 14,000 + 97 count portion is covered in the proposed duplicate