# I search for a term on Google : I have 94 results, another one with his own computer : 14,300. Why?

Tags: google-search

On a forum we argued about the usage (or not) of an abbreviation.

I said : *MSORPG* isn't a very used term. See my search with *Google* (94 results) :

[image: I found 94 results]

The one with whom I argued replied : "*Look, it is used a lot !*" (14,300 results).

[image: He founds 14,300 entries]

What can explain we have so much difference in our number of results?
I haven't checked any filter able to reduce my results (I think !).

Comment: @Rubén No, it's not the case : we are togheter on the first page of results. Searching for the same word.

Comment: I think that you missed the part were it say that the number of results is a rough estimate... have you both have review how that number changes on the the other pages?

Answer (score 0):

The number of results reported on the first page is an estimate. On the following pages it could be more precise. In this case, for me the last page of results is the page 10 which shows to me 98 as estimated number of results.

[image]

Related

- [Why on the first page Google says there are thousands of results but on the last page there are less than a hundred?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14972/88163)